# IOS App - Pay for video and download video after payment in app purchase is required or not?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

My application have video list available for uesrs if user like particular video he can purchase video and once payment done he can download it.

My question is does it comes under in app purchase of IOS ? Can I use pay pal as payment gateway instead of in app purchase ?

Comment: This will have to be a InApp Purchase, since the video is a digital good.

Comment: Thanks for reply but Once I downloaded video I can play that video without my application. I read on documentation that  digital content that can be delivered within your application will be in in app purchase please advice ?

Answer (score 0):

If a part of your app is being purchased from within the app, Apple requires that you use their app store to charge the customer. This is an inconvenience for most developers, but big companies like [Spotify](http://www.theverge.com/2015/7/8/8913105/spotify-apple-app-store-email) can have big problems with that. Using PayPal to purchase a part of your application would be grounds for [an immediate refusal](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies) of your app in the review process.